# Symfony 4 Forms - Persist collection of related forms

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm using Symfony 4 Forms as REST API data access layer.

I have a problem with persisting collection of related entities. The main (root) Entity is Shipping which has field for related Parcels which has field for related Loads.

One ShippingType has many ShippingParcelType which has many ShippingLoadType in other words.

When I persist brand new Shipping with brand new Parcels and Loads - everything looks good, but when I persist existing Parcel with a collection of existing and brand new Loads Symfony will accept only if collection starts from existing one with brand new ones at the end.

Let's say I persist like this (everything is cool, Symfony will persist):

```
{
    "shipping_id": 1000,
    "shipping_number": "Z/1000",
    "parcel": [
        {
            "parcel_id": 2000,
            "parcel_field": "etc...",
            "loads": [
                {
                    "load_id": 3000,
                    "load_address": "..."
                },
                {
                    "load_id": 4000,
                    "load_address": "..."
                },
                {
                    "load_id": null,
                    "load_address": "..."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I send request with given data as below (load with load_id null in the middle of collection), Symfony will throw error 500:

```
{
    "shipping_id": 1000,
    "shipping_number": "Z/1000",
    "parcel": [
        {
            "parcel_id": 2000,
            "parcel_field": "etc...",
            "loads": [
                {
                    "load_id": 3000,
                    "load_address": "..."
                },
                {
                    "load_id": null,
                    "load_address": "..."
                },
                {
                    "load_id": 4000,
                    "load_address": "..."
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Error message:
`Could not determine access type for property "id" in class "ClientBundle\Entity\Shipping\ShippingLoad": Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "addId()"/"removeId()", "setId()", "id()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "ClientBundle\Entity\Shipping\ShippingLoad"..`

Comment: Is you collection indexed by anything (id, position, slug, ...)? Have you tried adding `setId()` to  `ShippingLoad` as the error message suggests?

Comment: Some more code from your controller or service or whatever is relevant would also be helpful.

Comment: If I remember well, a Symfony CollectionType Form once it's rendered doesn't store in anyway the original Id of the entity, so it is based on the order of the collection to know which ones are edits and which are news (edits first, news last). So it detects an Id to be set for an entity that's new, and you don't have a setId function to set it, so it explodes.